# How to specify which channel to download Flutter infrastructure from?

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu, snapcraft

I use Ubuntu 20.04.
I downloaded Flutter from the Snap store (**Stable channel**).
When I initialized Flutter, it started to download **infrastructure from the beta channel** of its GitHub repository.

[image: Flutter edition downloaded from the Snap store]
[image: flutter_infra]

So, my question is:

1. Is it normal or something is going wrong?
2. Is there a way to make Flutter download the stable edition instead of the beta one from GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The best channel for making a stable app is `stable` channel,`beta` if web?
- You can change the channel to `stable` by running
  `flutter channel stable`